# Grails : How to set the x and y data of line chart?

Tags: grails

I'm using **Google Chart Plugin** in grails and I could not find a documentation for it. I want to create a lineChart but I dont how to set the data. This is what I've done so far but ofcourse it's not working because I'm using the wrong attributes.

```
<g:lineChart title="Daily Profit Chart" colors="${colors}"
      labels="['profit','date']" dataType='extended' dataSet[0]="[1,18,200,87,1090,44,3999]" dataSet[1]="[88,900,77,1,2998,4]"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the examples shown [here](https://github.com/bmuschko/grails-google-visualization/blob/master/grails-app/views/charts/index.gsp) you provide the series data as nested lists and information on the columns of the data.

You also need to use the gvisualization taglib provided by the [plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/google-visualization) (are you using an outdated version?).

Example

```
def seriesColumns = [['string', 'Year'], ['number', 'Quantity']]
def seriesData = [['2001', 100], ['2002', 120], ['2003', 142]]

<gvisualization:lineCoreChart
    elementId="container"
    columns="${seriesColumns}"
    data="${seriesData}"/>
```